# <embed> tag in HTML5 with alternate content like <object> tag?

Tags: html

In an <object> tag, you can put alternate content, like this:

```
<object data="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    <img alt="Image" src="image.png"/>
</object>
```

Is there a way to do the same (or something similar) with <embed> tag?

I suppose Javascript could be a solution, but I'm looking for something with only HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that embedding arbitrary data types is not yet possible. When loaded by a browser most unrecognized [mime types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) get interpreted as plain HTML.

It's pretty hard to get even basic media types to embed -- see audio and video, which are just starting to gain popular acceptance with HTML5. Most object tags you see are likely restricted to media types that are possible to load via proprietary desktop/browser extensions.

Comment: I wasn't aware of it. I was trying something like the example, a SVG image, that Opera shows but other browsers don't. Thanks!

Comment: Good news: That actually *is* one of the few well-supported mime types! http://caniuse.com/svg-html5 Example here: https://jwatt.org/svg/demos/xhtml-with-inline-svg.xhtml

Comment: Sorry, I never saw your comment, editor. I read something about inline svg, but never stopped to see how it works. Thanks!